# How to change hover action to click action?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Hello** people I created two divs and when i hover to h3 shows me something. I want display this only when i click on h3. How i can do this?

How to change hover to click? When i do this doesn't working.
Sorry for my bad language.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('li.requirement').hover(function () {
        $(this).find('span').show();
    }, function () {
        $(this).find('span').hide();
    });
});
```

```css
#wrap {
    background: #e7e7e7;
    padding: 0px; 
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;  
}

#left, #right {
     background: #ccc;
     display: inline-block;    
     padding: 20px;   
}


li {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

span.lewy {float:right; background:red; padding:20px;}
span.prawy {float:left; background:red; padding:20px;}

h3 {text-align:center;}

h3.praw {float:left;}
h3.lew {float:right;}

.calosc {max-width:500px; margin: 0 auto; border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="left"><div class="lef">

<li class="requirement" id="requirement_1">
     <h3 class="lew"><a href="#">SPR</a></h3>
 <span class="fr drag lewy" style="display:none;">1 kontakt</span>
</li>

</div></div>
    <div id="right"><div class="praf">

<li class="requirement" id="requirement_2">
     <h3 class="praw"><a href="#">SPR 2</a></h3>
 <span class="fr drag prawy" style="display:none;">2 kontakt</span>

</li>

</div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: $('li.requirement').hover this is a hover so what do you think a click is

Comment: Well start by using a `click` function...have you even tried that?

Comment: When I hover my cursor over it, it works just fine. What browser are you using?

Comment: $('li.requirement').hover( >>>>> $('li.requirement').click(

Comment: when i change .hover to .click doesen't work! sorry

Comment: You can't pass two functions as parameters like with hover. Pass only the first one and use `.toggle()` instead of hide when using click.

Comment: sorry can i please to working example on jsfiddle? When i do this not shows me this red divs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.on('click', function(){});` and then inside this function you check to see if it's already visible or not. Take a look here

**EDIT**
As you want to be just the `<h3>` clickable, i made an adjustment in the code below, and now you need to cehck for the visibility of the h3 parent, because now the context of `this` is now `h3` and no more the `li`

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.clickableH3').on('click', function () {  
        if ($(this.parentElement).find('span').is(":visible")){
          $(this.parentElement).find('span').hide();
        }else{
          $(this.parentElement).find('span').show();   
        }
    });
});
```

```css
#wrap {
    background: #e7e7e7;
    padding: 0px; 
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;  
}

#left, #right {
     background: #ccc;
     display: inline-block;    
     padding: 20px;   
}


li {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

span.lewy {float:right; background:red; padding:20px;}
span.prawy {float:left; background:red; padding:20px;}

h3 {text-align:center;}

h3.praw {float:left;}
h3.lew {float:right;}

.calosc {max-width:500px; margin: 0 auto; border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="left"><div class="lef">

<li class="requirement" id="requirement_1">
     <h3 class="lew clickableH3"><a href="#">SPR</a></h3>
 <span class="fr drag lewy" style="display:none;">1 kontakt</span>
</li>

</div></div>
    <div id="right"><div class="praf">

<li class="requirement" id="requirement_2">
     <h3 class="praw clickableH3"><a href="#">SPR 2</a></h3>
 <span class="fr drag prawy" style="display:none;">2 kontakt</span>

</li>

</div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: OK, Thank You but i click on red divs it close. I can open/close only when i click on h3?

Comment: You rox! Big THX !

Answer (score 0):

Well you see, in your js code, where you have "hover" ? Well you type "click" there instead ...

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery hover function can have 2 parameters, which is your case. The first one for the hover, the second is for the unhover

So if you want to be able to close and hide on click I advise to use some css and use toggleClass. But if you wan to keep only javascript you can do like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('li.requirement').click(function () {
        var $elm = $(this);
        if( $elm.hasClass('showed') ){
            $elm.find('span').removeClass('showed').hide();
        }else{
            $elm.find('span').addClass('showed').show();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I want open and close. How i can do that? Thank you this is part working

Comment: when i click h3 close doesen't working :/ I want h3 open/close